# How do you test a reactive mongo repository?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-data-mongodb-reactive

I'm trying to test the `findByPhoneNumber` method in this repository

```java
public interface UserRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<User, String> {

    Mono<User> findByPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber);

}
```

ATM, my test looks like this

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
class UserRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repository;

    @Test
    void findByPhoneNumber() {
        val phoneNumber = "11111 111111";

        val user = repository.save(User.builder().phoneNumber(phoneNumber).password("password").build());

        assertEquals(user, repository.findByPhoneNumber(phoneNumber));
    }

}
```

When I run it, I get this error

`org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'io.freesale.repository.UserRepositoryTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'io.freesale.repository.UserRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}`

I'm a Spring noob so please don’t bully me too hard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing the `@DataMongoTest` annotation

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28459188)

Comment: That is a complete answer